# API to convert a sms to plain english?

Tags: java

I am developing a natural language processing project where an user can use SMS language in it. So I just want to know that Is there any api to convert a SMS to plain english language?

Comment: How do you define sms langauge? Do you have grammer for it?

Comment: sms? As in 'short message service'? Then I don't think so.

Comment: If this is really about converting "u" into "you", then I guess you'll be walking into [tag:nlp] territory as soon as you get past those trivial conversions.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a HashMap to convert these txt speak words into real works. For example

```
private Map<String, String> convertMap = new HashMap<>(){{
    put("IMHO", "in my humble opinion");
    put("LOL", "laugh our loud");
}};
```

If you wanted you could wrap this map in a class with an interface which you can code against. This interface would be your library API. If you found that the map was getting too large then you could change the implementation and not affect your calling code

```
public interface TxtConverter {
    String convertToText(String txtSpeak);
}
```

Your class extending this could then contain the HashMap. The convertToText method you would be forced to implement could do the search, exception handling etc.

Comment: Dam, I thought "IMHO" stood for "in my honest opinion" - I'm so not down with the kids :<

Comment: @david99world you've given me doubts now...perhaps it is ;)